# putting data into categories (buckets) based on a value

Tags: oracle

how can i assign a category based on a value?

for example, i have a table with values from 1-200. how do i assign a category to each record, like 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc.

i can do it using the below but that seems like a bad solution.

sorry, this is probably very basic but i don't know what it's called and googling buckets (as it's called in our company) didn't bring up any results.

thank you

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountOfSA,
 CASE
              WHEN CountOfSA BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN
                   '1-5'
              WHEN CountOfSA BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN
                   '6-10'
              WHEN CountOfSA BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN
                   '11-15'
              WHEN CountOfSA BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN
                   '16-20'
              WHEN CountOfSA BETWEEN 21 AND 25 THEN
                   '21-25'
              WHEN CountOfSA BETWEEN 26 AND 30 THEN
                   '26-30'
         END
              AS diff
              FROM NR_CF_212
```

Comment: If it is more than just a few possibilities, I would probably put these bucket ranges into a separate table and join to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [WIDTH_BUCKET](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions234.htm#SQLRF06163) function. 
This divides the range into equal sized intervals and assigns a bucket number to each interval.

```
with x as (
    select CountOfSA, 
    width_bucket(CountOfSA, 1, 200, 40) bucket_
    from NR_CF_212
    )
select CountOfSA, 
       cast(1 + (bucket_ - 1)*5 as varchar2(4)) ||
       '-' ||
       cast( bucket_*5 as varchar2(4)) diff
from x
order by CountOfSA;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/842d8/6).

Comment: this is so elegant)))))

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use concatenate together some calculated values to dynamically create the bucket name:

```
select countofsa
      , ((countofsa - 1)/5) * 5 + 1
      , ((countofsa - 1)/5 + 1) * 5 
      , ((countofsa - 1)/5) * 5 + 1 || '-' || ((countofsa - 1)/5 + 1) * 5 AS diff
  from nr_cf_212
```

Some output:

```
 countofsa | ?column? | ?column? | diff
-----------+----------+----------+-------
         1 |        1 |        5 | 1-5
         2 |        1 |        5 | 1-5
         3 |        1 |        5 | 1-5
         4 |        1 |        5 | 1-5
         5 |        1 |        5 | 1-5
         6 |        6 |       10 | 6-10
         7 |        6 |       10 | 6-10
         8 |        6 |       10 | 6-10
         9 |        6 |       10 | 6-10
        10 |        6 |       10 | 6-10
        11 |       11 |       15 | 11-15
(11 rows)
```

UPDATE from comments, Oracle example, dynamically computing range:

```
create table nr_cf_212(countofsa number);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(1);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(2);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(3);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(4);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(5);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(6);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(7);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(9);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(10);
insert into nr_cf_212 values(11);

select countofsa
      , TRUNC((countofsa - 1)/5) * 5 + 1
      , (TRUNC((countofsa - 1)/5) + 1) * 5 
      , TRUNC((countofsa - 1)/5) * 5 + 1 || '-' || (TRUNC((countofsa - 1)/5) + 1) * 5 AS diff
  from nr_cf_212;


| COUNTOFSA | TRUNC((COUNTOFSA-1)/5)*5+1 | (TRUNC((COUNTOFSA-1)/5)+1)*5 |  DIFF |
|-----------|----------------------------|------------------------------|-------|
|         1 |                          1 |                            5 |   1-5 |
|         2 |                          1 |                            5 |   1-5 |
|         3 |                          1 |                            5 |   1-5 |
|         4 |                          1 |                            5 |   1-5 |
|         5 |                          1 |                            5 |   1-5 |
|         6 |                          6 |                           10 |  6-10 |
|         7 |                          6 |                           10 |  6-10 |
|         9 |                          6 |                           10 |  6-10 |
|        10 |                          6 |                           10 |  6-10 |
|        11 |                         11 |                           15 | 11-15 |
```

I tried it with sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b922e/4).

I broke it into parts to show the "from" column, the "to" column and then the range. If you divide your number by 5 and look at the quotient and the remainder, you will see a pattern:

```
1/5 = 0 remainder 1
2/5 = 0 remainder 2
3/5 = 0 remainder 3
4/5 = 0 remainder 4
5/5 = 1 remainder 0
6/5 = 1 remainder 1
7/5 = 1 remainder 2
8/5 = 1 remainder 3
9/5 = 1 remainder 4
10/5 = 2 remainder 0
11/5 = 2 remainder 1
```

The range for the number is "from" 5 times the quotient "to" 5 times the quotient plus the remainder -almost.  Actually, everything is offset by 1. So take your number, subtract 1, then do the division.

Comment: this is definitely creative except in my data i'm getting things like 1-5, 2-6. trying to figure out how you did this to understand why it's doing that. interesting solution still

Comment: You probably have different results under Oracle because `/` is returning a fractional NUMBER where as in my test, on Postgres, this was returning truncated value.  In Oracle, wrap the `/` divisions with `TRUNC` so `((countofsa - 1)/5)` becomes `TRUNC(((countofsa - 1)/5))`, etc. Then your ranges should be correct and dynamically calculated.

Comment: nope))) same thing, i even created a fake table with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. but i don't understand how this would work

Answer (score 0):

I would put the range values and descriptions into a separate table, especially if you plan to use these for future queries, views, etc.  Plus its easier to change the ranges or descriptions as needed.  For example:

```
create table sales_ranges
(
low_val number not null,
high_val number not null,
range_desc varchar2(100) not null
)
cache;

insert into sales_ranges values (0,1000,'$0-$1k');
insert into sales_ranges values (1001,10000,'$1k-$10k');
insert into sales_ranges values (10001,100000,'$10k-$100k');
insert into sales_ranges values (100001,1000000,'$100k-$1mm');
insert into sales_ranges values (1000001,10000000,'$1mm-$10mm');
insert into sales_ranges values (10000001,100000000,'$10mm-$100mm');
commit;


create table sales
(
id number,
total_sales number
);

insert into sales(id, total_sales) 
-- some random values for testing
select level, trunc(dbms_random.value(1,10000000))
from dual
connect by level <= 100;

commit;

select id, total_sales, range_desc
from sales s
left outer join sales_ranges sr 
  on (s.total_sales between sr.low_val and sr.high_val)
order by s.id
;
```

Output (just first 3 rows):

```
ID  TOTAL_SALES RANGE_DESC
1   5122380 $1mm-$10mm
2   347726  $100k-$1mm
3   6564700 $1mm-$10mm
```

Comment: this still requires writing out all possibilities, there are 100 of them. what if at some point there are more than 100? thank you for trying. i was looking for a function (width_bucket it turns out) that does it dynamically. i should've been more clear about what i'm looking for, sorry :)